# Require One of a Set of Fields in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony1, yaml, propel

I have an entity, let's call 'machine', which has a group of entities from which it takes its name. At least one of these fields is required, but more than one can be set. So in the example below, if the host name and IP is not set, then the service tag should be. I am using Propel 1.5 as an ORM.

```
machine:
  id: ~
  hostname:    {type: varchar(255)}
  ip:          {type: varchar(255)}
  service_tag: {type: varchar(255)}
```

An article on [multi-column constraints](http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2007/05/23/multi-column-constraints-in-sql/) makes me wonder if it would be possible to add something like `required(hostname, mac, service_tag)`. If this is the case, how would I accomplish this in .yml form for Propel?

Comment: You could make a multi-column index that is required to be unique.

Comment: How would the unique composite index handle multiple instances of {hostname="MOE", IP = null, service-tag = NULL}?

Comment: @Tim - It would not allow them.  This might not be what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`At least one of these [three] fields is required`

You might concatenate the three, first converting null to empty string:

```
           CONCAT(   ifnull(host,'') , ifnull(ip,'') , ifnull(tag,'')  )
```

and then this constraint:

```
         length(   CONCAT(   ifnull(host,'') , ifnull(ip,'') , ifnull(tag,'')  )  ) > 0
```

***if mySQL supported check constraints.***

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how I might write this in .yml for Propel?

Comment: @Druckles: I believe you would have to implement this CHECK in a trigger, not as a bona-fide CHECK constraint, because of limitations in mySQL. I have not worked with .yml but would be surprised if it supported a way to declare triggers. Maybe as a plug-in "behavior"?

Comment: I guess I'll be using the save() method to ensure this, then. Fortunately it's not a crucial component of the project. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM machine
 WHERE hostname IS NULL
       AND ip IS NULL
       AND service_tag IS NULL;
```

If this resultset is not the empty set then the business rule has been violated. Therefore, create a constraint or trigger that tests this.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible with symfony and propel. But you can set up your symfony form that it requires one of the three columns.